# NumberFormat doesn't take the value from updated state on change

Tags: validation, next.js, setstate, react-number-format

I am trying to prevent typing 0 (zero) at the beginning of phone number after the country code.

I am using:

- Next.Js
- NumberFormat (react-number-format)

**The problem:**
I was able to prevent 0 from typing. When I run console.log(number);, it works as I want however NumberFormat doesn't take number as a value. It basically doesn't update. I have no idea how I can prevent 0 at the beginning.

On top of that allowLeadingZeros={false} doesn't work as well.

**Expected result:**
If I start typing 0, it should remove it. For example if I am typing 06 99 99 99 99, it should show +33 6 99 99 99 99 by removing 0 at the beginning.

I don't know what am I missing. I noticed it works sometimes.

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
    
    export default function FormContact(props, initialValues = {}) {
      const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
    
      const onValueChangeNumber = (e) => {
        if (/^0/.test(e.value)) {
          e.value = e.value.replace(/^0/, "");
          setNumber(e.value);
        }
        console.log("If there is no zero, it worked", number); //This shows 0 prevented at the beginning as expected.
        console.log("Formatted Change", e.value); //This shows 0 prevented at the beginning as expected.
      };
    
      const onChangeNumber = (e) => {
        console.log("Normal Change", e.target.value); //This shows 0 at the beginning.
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <NumberFormat
            type="tel"
            key="phoneNumber"
            name="tel"
            placeholder="Téléphone"
            value={number}
            onValueChange={onValueChangeNumber}
            onChange={onChangeNumber}
            allowLeadingZeros={false}
            format="+33 # ## ## ## ##"
            mask="_"
          />
        </>
      );
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.